# SQL Server 2008 to 2014 migration and .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

We are investigating for a migration of our database (SQL Server 2008) to a new server with SQL Server 2014. We have a website using it built in ASP.NET with the .NET Framework 4.0.

Do you know some things we should pay attention to? Is there any things to change in our way to connect to it? We are currently using things from `System.Data.SqlClient` and a simple connection string like

```
server=SERVEUR;database=DATABASE;User Id=USER;password=PWD;
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The connection string should be fine, as should the classes you are using to represent the database items (connections, transactions, commands). There is a good chance the migration will work without issue if you are not using anything overly complicated, but you won't be taking much advantage of the new features or data types without additional work afterwards. We are going through something similar at the moment on a large enterprise app and we haven't hit any snags.

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! That was our conclusion also but we were looking for a confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection must be fine.
No breaking changes:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143179%28v=sql.120%29.aspx